# Understanding semisimple Z modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, simplicial-stuff

I'm trying to understand the nature of semisimplicity in Z modules.

So for instance would I be right in thinking $Z/30Z \oplus Z/2Z$ is semi simple as it can be expressed as $Z/3Z \oplus Z/5Z \oplus Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z$ ?

Similarly is $Z/20Z \oplus Z/7Z$ semi simple as it's expressed as $Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z \oplus Z/5Z \oplus Z/7Z$

Are all prime order modules simple? So say $Z/101Z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only simple abelian groups are the cyclic groups of prime order (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/proof-that-all-abelian-simple-groups-are-cyclic-groups-of-prime-order)). Thus an abelian group is semisimple if and only if it is isomorphic to a sum of such groups. As a consequence, there is a unique semisimple abelian group of order $n$ for every integer $n$.

Also $Z/20Z$ is not isomorphic to $Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z \oplus Z/5Z$ since the latter has no elements of order 4. In particular it is not semisimple.

Comment: Thank you that clears things up a bit, but how do we know if a group is isomorphic to simple groups?

Comment: Just check if it is cyclic of prime order

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, I mean how do we show a group is semisimple i.e isomorphic to product of simple groups

Comment: $A$ is semisimple iff for every prime $p$ dividing the order of $A$, there  are no elements of order $p^k$ for $k>1$. Is that the kind of characterization you want?

Comment: Yes! That's perfect thank you so much